# How to force variables of differential equations to be Real numbers. a question arising from the warning: "NDSolve::evfrf: "

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I numerically  solving a ode with the following code, warnings named "evfrf" prompted.

I am wondering how to force variables of differential equations to be Real numbers

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] + .1 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 0, y'[0] == 1, 
y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y[t], 
"EventCondition" -> y'[t] > 0, 
"EventAction" :> Print[t, ", ", y[t], ", ", y'[t]]}]
```

warning message:

```
NDSolve::evfrf: 
The event function did not evaluate to a real number somewhere 
between t =  1.5798366385128957` and t = 1.6426647495929725`,
preventing FindRoot from finding the root accurately. >>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue of the answer genuinely being a complex number at those points.
The following does not give an error.

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] + .1 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 0, y'[0] == 1, 
 y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 20}]

Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

The issue is the attempt to find the zero in `y'[t]` and limitations in the implied root-finding process. I tried increasing the `WorkingPrecision` and the `MaxSteps` but it didn't remove the error.

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] + .10`64 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 0, y'[0] == 1, 
y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
  Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y[t], 
 "EventCondition" -> y'[t] >= 0, 
 "EventAction" :> Print[t, ", ", y[t], ", ", y'[t]]},  
   MaxSteps -> 10^9, MaxStepSize -> 0.0001, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
```

Unless you really care about the eighth or subsequent decimal place, I would suggest not worrying about this error.

Those more expert than me in numerical analysis might disagree, but I work in a field where we usually don't have any faith in the accuracy of any data past the first decimal place of a percentage change (third decimal place of a level).

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems to be caused by the `"EventCondition" -> y'[t] >= 0` part only. I don't know what the problem is there, but given that you want to restrict events (y[t]==0) to passages going up (y'[t]>0), you can replace that part with `"Direction" -> 1` which does the same.

Alternatively, you could simply switch off the message using `Off[NDSolve::evfrf]` as it doesn't seem to make a difference in the final result. The `"Direction" -> 1` method yields the same events as the original one which generated the messages.

Answer (score 1):

is it important to use the EventLocator? is it possible to solve for y' and then apply FindRoot on it? something like:

```
ndsolveOptions = {MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
  Method ->{"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 10,PrecisionGoal -> 10};

sol = First@NDSolve[{y''[t] + .1 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 0, y'[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, 
     {y[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, Sequence@ndsolveOptions];

der = y'[t] /. sol;
Plot[der, {t, 1.2, 1.7}]

FindRoot[der, {t, 1.6}]

      {t -> 1.614}
```

[image]